# Sql to mongodb Query

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$sql_select = $db->db_query("SELECT
        user_id,
        resubmit_count,
        user_id,
        id,
            title,
        tags,
        added_date 
    FROM 
        admin_self_care 
    WHERE 
        status='1' AND 
        user_type='2' AND 
        selfcare_reviewer_status='0' AND 
        user_id='".$_SESSION['login_user_id']."' 
    group by id 
    order by id desc");
```

I have above sql query i want to convert into mongodb

I tried this way. Connection is successfully established still getting response blank.

```
$filter = [
    'status' => '1',
    'user_type' => '2',
    'selfcare_reviewer_status' => '0',
    'user_id' => $_SESSION['login_user_id']
];

$options = [
    'sort' => ['id' => -1],
    'projection' => [
        'user_id' => 1,
        'resubmit_count' => 1,
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 1,
        'tags' => 1,
        'added_date' => 1
    ],
    'collation' => ['locale' => 'en'],
];

$result = $collection->find($filter, $options);
```

Please correct me

Comment: Your SQL query will fail due to `group by id`. Apart from that your query looks OK. Check the syntax and parameters of the php command.

Comment: i want to correct my mongodb query is there any need to change

Comment: fixed the above issue